# Independence of premise, right to left

Tags: logic, independence

When one aims to prove in classical logic that

$\alpha \rightarrow \exists x \beta(x) \vdash \exists x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta(x))$

does one need to ask $x$ not to occur free in $\alpha$? It seems to me that this request is unnecessary (of course, being required to prove the converse). Am I wrong?

Comment: In classical logic it must work... Rewrite them as: $\lnot \alpha \lor \exists x \beta(x)$ and $\exists x \lnot \alpha \lor \exists x \beta(x)$ (distributing $\exists$ over $\lor$) respectively. Now we have to use $\lor$-elim (proof by cases) and we have no restrictions on $\alpha$.

Comment: Ok, great. Thank you. In the Wikipedia page about this principle, there is written that $x$ must not occur free in $\alpha$ but this is an unnecessary requirement. Maybe they were mislead by it being required in the converse case.

Comment: What can be interesting, is to find a (classical) derivation in e.g. Natural Deduction... In order to mimick the above informal argument, we need LEM (or DN).

Comment: Of course we have the following derivation

1. $\neg \exists x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta(x))$, Assumption; 2. $\alpha \rightarrow \exists x \beta(x)$, Assumption; 3. $\beta(x)$, Assumption; 4. $\forall x (\alpha \wedge \neg \beta(x))$, from 1 by converting $\exists$ in $\forall$; 5. $\alpha \wedge \neg \beta(x)$, from 2 by $\forall$-elim; 6. $\alpha$, by $\wedge$-elim; 7. $\exists x \beta(x)$, from 6 and 2 by modus ponens; FOLLOWS BELOW

Comment: 8. $\neg \beta(x)$, from 5 by $\wedge$-elim; 9. $\bot$, from 3 and 8; 10. $\bot$, from 9, by discharging 2 by $\exists$-elim; 11. $\neg \neg \exists x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta(x))$, from 1 by discharging it by $\neg$-intr ; 12. $\exists x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta(x))$, from 11 by DN.

Comment: We ask no restriction on $\alpha$, in particular it could be that $x \in FV(\alpha)$.

Comment: Comments: how you apply $\exists$-elim to 2. in 10 ?

Comment: It seems to me that you have not discharged assumption 3.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong in numbering. So 1. $\neg \exists x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta(x))$, ASS; 2. $\alpha \rightarrow \beta(x)$, ASS; 3. $\beta(x)$, ASS; 4. $\forall x (\alpha \wedge \neg \beta(x))$ from 1 by converting $\exists$ in $\forall$; 5. $\alpha \wedge \neg \beta(x)$ from 4 by $\forall$-elim; 6. $\alpha$, from 5 by $\wedge$-elim; 7. $\exists \beta(x)$, from 6 and 2 by modus ponens; FOLLOWS BELOW

Comment: 8. $\neg \beta(x)$ from 5 by $\wedge$-elim; 9. $\bot$ from 3 and 8; 10 $\bot$ from 9 by $\exists$-elim discharging 3; 11. $\neg \neg \exists x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta(x))$ by $\neg$-intr discharging 1; 12. $\exists x(\alpha \rightarrow \beta(x))$ from 11 by DN.

Comment: Assumption 2 above should of course be changed in $\alpha \rightarrow \exists x \beta(x)$, sorry I was wrong again in writing